# Reverse for 'post-list' not found. 'post-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I'm still within the very early stages of learning Django and I have just ran in to this error (I am following a tutorial, not too sure where I've messed up!)

"Reverse for 'post-list' not found. 'post-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

In my template file here is how my template tag looks:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    href="{% url 'post-list' %}" 
    {% else %}
```

As for my URLs.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='post-list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/edit/<int:pk>/', PostEditView.as_view(), name='post-edit'),
    path('post/delete/<int:pk>/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/delete/<int:pk>/', CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment-delete'),
    path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/<int:pk>/like', AddCommentLike.as_view(), name='comment-like'),
    path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/<int:pk>/dislike', AddCommentDislike.as_view(), name='comment-dislike'),
    path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/<int:pk>/reply', CommentReplyView.as_view(), name='comment-reply'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/like', AddLike.as_view(), name='like'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/dislike', AddDislike.as_view(), name='dislike'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('profile/edit/<int:pk>/', ProfileEditView.as_view(), name='profile-edit'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/followers/', ListFollowers.as_view(), name='list-followers'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/followers/add', AddFollower.as_view(), name='add-follower'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/followers/remove', RemoveFollower.as_view(), name='remove-follower'),
    path('search/', UserSearch.as_view(), name='profile-search'),
    path('notification/<int:notification_pk>/post/<int:post_pk>', PostNotification.as_view(), name='post-notification'),
    path('notification/<int:notification_pk>/profile/<int:profile_pk>', FollowNotification.as_view(), name='follow-notification'),
    path('notification/<int:notification_pk>/thread/<int:object_pk>', ThreadNotification.as_view(), name='thread-notification'),
    path('notification/delete/<int:notification_pk>', RemoveNotification.as_view(), name='notification-delete'),
    path('inbox/', ListThreads.as_view(), name='inbox'),
    path('inbox/create-thread/', CreateThread.as_view(), name='create-thread'),
    path('inbox/<int:pk>/', ThreadView.as_view(), name='thread'),
    path('inbox/<int:pk>/create-message/', CreateMessage.as_view(), name='create-message'),
]
```

EDIT: Traceback provided below:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://*/

Django Version: 3.2.2
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['social',
 'core',
 'crispy_forms',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/myapp/core/templates/landing/navbar.html, error at line 11
   Reverse for 'post-list' not found. 'post-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   1 : {% load custom_tags %}
   2 : 
   3 : <div class="container">
   4 : <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
   5 :   <div class="container-fluid">
   6 :     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   7 :       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   8 :     </button>
   9 :     <a class="navbar-brand" 
   10 :     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   11 :     href=" {% url 'post-list' %} " 
   12 :     {% else %}
   13 :     href="{% url 'index' %}"
   14 :     {% endif %}
   15 : 
   16 :     ><i class="fas fa-comment"></i> Social Network</a>
   17 :     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
   18 :       <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
   19 :       </ul>
   20 :       <form class="d-flex" method="GET" action="">
   21 :         <div class="input-group">


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myapp/core/views.py", line 6, in get
    return render(request, 'landing/index.html')
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 195, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 172, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'post-list' not found. 'post-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Updated (root) URLs.py

```
"""socialnetwork URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('social/', include('social.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Could anyone give me any pointers with this?

Thanks,
Jay.

Comment: Did you specify an `app_name` in your `urls.py`?

Comment: Hey Willem, thank you so much for the very speedy response! :-) At the top of the URLs.py file, I have the following code in place: ``` from django.urls import path
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView, PostEditView, PostDeleteView, CommentDeleteView, ProfileView, ProfileEditView, AddFollower, RemoveFollower, AddLike, AddDislike, UserSearch, ListFollowers, AddCommentLike, AddCommentDislike, CommentReplyView, PostNotification, FollowNotification, ThreadNotification, RemoveNotification, CreateThread, ListThreads ``` but I haven't actually included my actual app name in there..

Comment: please [edit] your question.

Comment: Sorry! I'm not sure how you format code blocks within the comment section :)

Comment: is there a place where you *`included`* the `urlpatterns` defined here? (likely the "root" `urls.py`)?

Comment: I've checked my root URLs.py file, `urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]`  - The post-list view however, is listed in a different app directory called "social" which isn't listed as included above.

Comment: well since it is not listed, there is no way to get from the "root" to that view. You thus will need to include the social urls somehow in the root urls.

Comment: Ah okay, I may have overlooked a section of the tutorial i am following, I will reflect back and see if there's something I've missed! (There must be something somewhere) Thank you so much for helping the best you could! Really appreciated my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you defined the path in the `urls.py` of the `social` module. As a result there is no path from the "root url" to the url that triggers the `post-list` view, and thus it can not determine the path of that view name.

You should include this, for example with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
  , path('', include('core.urls'))
  , path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))
  , path('social/', include('social.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Thanks Willem! I'm going to try your suggestion now :-) This is the tutorial - https://legionscript.medium.com/ - the tutorial is only partially developed (16 tutorials) altogether and i think the author of the course is still adding further tutorials, but he has covered most part of everything that should be required to get the app up and running (I believe) - I'm just working my way through past previous lessons to see if I've missed anything obvious)

Comment: Ah yes, he has referenced this stage (which you have mentioned correctly above) (I've added in the paths, but I'm still getting the same error annoyingly!! `urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('social/', include('social.urls')),
]`

Comment: @Jarjar95: can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67653150/edit) your question with the complete traceback?

Comment: Edited my question with the traceback! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Jarjar: but did you add the `social.urls` with `path('social/', include('social.urls'))`?

Comment: @Jajar95: you can find this `urls.py` in a subdirectory with the same name as the name of the project (not the app).

Comment: I've edited my question of the URLs.py within my project folder rather than my app folder, but yes, the path's you are referring to are there :) I'm so confused!